# Python CGI does not print after File I/O

Tags: python, html, cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi
print "Content-type: text/html"
print

print """
<html>

<head><title>your details are as follows</title></head>

<body>

  <h3> Sample CGI Script </h3>
"""

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
username = form.getvalue('Username')
ipaddress = form.getvalue('IPaddress')
subnetmask = form.getvalue('Subnetmask')

print username
print ipaddress
print subnetmask
```

The python code above works fine and prints out the html along with the username, ipaddress and subnetmask print statements above.
However, when I add the below code, any print statement after the FIle I/O does not get printed to the webpage. All prints above the File I/O are printed to the webpage in any case

```
searchfile = open("IP.txt", "r")
for line in searchfile:
    if ipaddress in line: print "IP set to null already"
searchfile.close()
```

Can anyone please explain to me how to get this to work. I really want the print statement `if ipaddress in line: print "IP set to null already"` to be printed onto the webpage

Comment: do you get any error? also, you need proper indentation. the print statement should be on the next line under the `if` statement

Comment: Search webserver's error log for an error. I guess "IP.txt" is not in the same directory as the script (in that case use full path to the file) or the file has wrong permissions and the script cannot read it (make it webserver-readable or all-readable).

Comment: the file IP.txt is in the same directory. Also, the indentation isn't a problem.I tried it with having the print statement below the if statement. The problem is the code won't print anything to the webpage after the File I/O operation

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your `open` call is not failing? Put a `try...except` around it and print a message if it fails.